# How to link membership provider with a database table?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Since the membership provider does not allow me to add additional fields for a new user like First Name, Last Name, etc, I want to store all that information into a seperate database table called Users. How do I link the membership provider with this table, so that when an Admin wants to manage users using a seperate webpage (not the buit-in membership provider page) it shows all the information in the membership provider plus the information in the database table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to link with `aspnet_Users` table. This [article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) has an overview of the membership provider tables.